# Using Javascript for styling content

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a problem to using javascript for styling content?

My website requires javascript.  There is this text on my website that I want vertically centered.  The text could be either 2 lines or 3 lines long.  With javascript I could vertically center it pretty easily.  The CSS ways to vertically center it seem complicated and include IE hacks.

So, is there a downside to me using javascript for this styling, considering I have already decided that my website will require javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The downside is that if you have any long-running page, say an ad fails to load, etc hanging the document.ready event...your styling wouldn't be applied until the document completed rendering and the javascript then ran.  *(Note: This assumes your script fires in the ready event, usually the case since you'd want the elements to be there)*

Basically you'd get a flash of non-styled content in the case of anything delaying the ready event.  Whether that matters, up to you, but personally I'd stick to CSS where possible.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes using JavaScript for seemingly simple styling is unavoidable; if I have to use JavaScript in this kind of scenario I just try to make it degrade as well as possible, ensuring that whilst a user without JavaScript doesn't get the full experience from the website, they don't get a bad one either.

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally use display: table-cell, and vertical-align:middle. Then in IE8+ and all other browsers it's centered, in older ones it won't be, but generally things like vertically aligned text aren't that vital to the design anyway.

Comment: In this scenario I'd probably also do this too, and if concerned by <IE8 I'd back it up with some conditional JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a downside. If you say it's going to be easier and considering that JavaScipt is the de facto client side language, go for it. Just make sure it'll work on modern browsers...

Just a point: CSS is meant to be used to do this kind of work, but it's not a rule. There are exceptions as is your case.